# VBA Excel - to exit sub when user cancels GetSaveAsFilename pop up box

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code which assigns to a button. When the button is pushed, it creates a new workbook and asks the user where to save the new file.

I want to make sure that if the user clicks cancel then it closes the new workbook and exits the sub.

I have wrote it as below but I don't know how to write a better code. I know that the `if` can be improved.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_a_new_workbook_and_save_it()

Dim xlPath As String

Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xlPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Title:="Select where you want to save your file") & "xlsm"

If xlPath = "Falsexlsm" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=xlPath, FileFormat:=52

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with the `If` statement as it is, but if you don't do the `Workbooks.Add` until **after** the `If`, you can avoid having to do the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` inside the `If`.

Comment: @YowE3K You are absolutely right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The above code working fine as you want....

Comment: I thought if I could rewrite the if statement in another shape. I think that there is better way to write it instead of using 'xlPath'.